# How do I 'Forget' saved network credentials

Tags: networking, seahorse

[image]Brand new to Ubuntu.  Tried to connect to an AFP server and checked off the 'save password forever' option. Used the wrong password and now I can't connect.  No where I can find to delete this saved password (even in the password manager).

Tried seahorse but the entry is not in there.

The `JASPER(AFP)` now connects automatically but because the auth is wrong all I get is the Public folder.  If I use the correct auth I get all the correct shares etc.  This a fresh install of 18.04.

Comment: Are you referring to credentials input to the "Connect to Server" option in the default file manager? if so, it depends on what version of Ubuntu you are using iirc - see for example [Bionic Beaver Nautilus list of visited servers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062552/bionic-beaver-nautilus-list-of-visited-servers/1113947)

Comment: Added a picture to the post for clarity.  Tried that other answer but no luck there.

Comment: If Jasper is under your control, just change the password, then when you try and connect, the saved password will be wrong, and you'll be prompted to enter the correct password, and then you can change the password back if you like.

Comment: The current saved password is already wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It must have some sort of timeout - tried again today and it asked for a password.  Still would like to know how to fix this.